# Split-Screen in Android App Development

Tags: android, split-screen

I was wondering if there was a way I can have part of my screen in android constantly display something, even something as simple as a piece of text or an image. I am fairly familiar with Android Development, so if there is a way to make an app that does that, it'd be great.
To be precise, I want the top third of my screen to stay constant, and the bottom two-thirds to work normally such that I can do anything I can normally do

Edit: I want the top third to display the constant text/image even if I exit the app. A widget is a good idea. I'll look more into that.

Comment: are you talking about widget screen ?

Comment: Can't you just create a layout with your "constant" content and for the bottom two-thirds of that layout include a FrameLayout, using fragments to change that content as needed?

Comment: I would suggest you to use *System Alert Window* like you see in facebook chat heads. See this example http://androidsrc.net/facebook-chat-like-floating-chat-heads/